# Is brew with burned steeping bag safe to drink?

Tags: all-grain, steeping, burner

My pot burned a tiny portion, about an inch across, of the steeping bag for an all-grain recipe prior to the boil. Is the beer still safe to drink? What off-flavors can that produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on having done it myself, you will possibly have a burned, smoky flavor and not in a good way. Whether it's safe to drink depends at least partially on what the bag is made of.  If the bag was muslin, it's likely safe.  If it was nylon, I'd be more worried.

Comment: Good to know, would the burned, smoky flavor be noticeable in the beer after a week of fermentation?

Comment: Based on my experience, it will never go away.

Comment: Well, I suppose what I meant to ask was if I can't taste a burn flavor after a week of fermentation it isn't likely that I will taste it later on in the process? Trying to decide whether to ditch the batch or not.

Comment: Yep, it you can't taste it now, it won't develop later.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the same thing with a hop sock. I'm pretty sure there nothing in them that could be harmful IMO. I was lucky and did if with an IPA so couldn't taste anything.